# Generating EAN 13 code

Tags: php, barcode

which is the easiest way to generate EAN 13 code? I want to implement it to my xml feed. Now I have only SKU number which is 50, 51, 52, 445 .. -it can be 1-5 digit.

Comment: What exactly do you mean? An image?

Comment: No, only a 13 digit number (=which is compatible with EAN13)

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Doesn't  an EAN13 code have a country and vendor ID? Where would those come from?

Comment: What? Generate a EAN-13 code? Usually one doesn't generate it, but _registers_ it. Or do you want a simple barcode that isn't necessarily EAN?

Comment: For what I need: there is a product catalog for eshops, to where eshops can upload their XML feed with products. I need simple number barcode for my products, because this product catalog needs that. So I need: x number+SKU(can be 1-5 digit)=13 digit number

Comment: Do NOT claim to have an EAN you haven't. If you supply products, and an EAN is required, register with GS1 and you'll get your numbers. EAN's are unique, that's what they are used for. You cannot be 'compatible with ean-13', you either have the numbers or you don't.

Comment: Don't the products already have a EAN13 code assigned?

Comment: @pekka Unfortunatelly not. I sell bikes and there is no EAN13 code. @Wrikken this EAN13 code is only visible to that regional product catalog service, nothing else.

Comment: If you resell bikes from a larger brand, they'll have them. If you build a consistent line of your own from scratch, you can register. If you make custom builds, EAN's are next to useless. Making them up is not an option, because you won't have the guarantee that it isn't the number of an existing product. Regional or otherwise, that's a nogo.

Comment: @Adrian still, @Wrikken has a very good point - I can tell from experience that showing EAN13 codes that aren't properly registered is not a good idea. They might spread outside your system, or used as identifiers in third party systems, leading to all sorts of trouble. Is simply using  `00000000000` out of the question? What is your end purpose, what are the bar codes needed for?

Comment: Oh, and BTW: custom builds usually don't have an EAN indeed, but any decent product catalog service that accepts custom one-off builds will usually accept items without EAN or they are bad at their job.

Comment: I asked service provider, and EAN is not necessary anymore, If I haven't one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a [PEAR package](http://pear.php.net/package/Image_Barcode) that allows you to generate bar codes. Is this what you search for?

Comment: Not 100%, I don't need image, just an EAN 13 digit number for a product catalog. x number+SKU(can be 1-5 digit)=13 digit number